# authlogic openid: fullname is not a defined simple registration field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic-oid

I finally got an open id demo app going:

- rails 2.3.5
- authlogic openid

When I create a new user in the database, I get the following error:

`fullname is not a defined simple registration field`

This is after I authorize the localhost,etc.

I don't have fullname anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: It's rather strange, since [fullname](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html#response_format) is a defined SREG field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a string rather than a symbol. I had the same issue with the email field until I made this change.

```
name = registration['fullname'] # Success
name = registration[:fullname] # Fail
```